# Indexes not being shown as possible keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have a couple queries which I created 2 separate indexes for, and I understand at the moment it doesn't really need to use them as the table doesn't contain that many rows; however they aren't even listed as a `possible key` when I use an `EXPLAIN`.

An example query is:

```
SELECT 
    id,eventname,details,datestart,dateend,smallimage
FROM
    `events`
WHERE
    CAST(dateend AS DATE) >= CURDATE()
AND
    (state='VIC' OR state = 'ALL')
AND
    STATUS = 1
ORDER BY
    datestart ASC;
```

The alternate query just adds another `AND` clause before the state, an example being:

```
 AND eventcat = 15
```

Now, I have added the following two indexes:

```
KEY `NewIndex4` (`dateend`,`state`,`status`,`datestart`),
KEY `NewIndex5` (`dateend`,`eventcat`,`state`,`status`,`datestart`)
```

However, MySQL only shows the below index as a possible key:

```
KEY `NewIndex1` (`state`,`status`,`frontpage`,`image`)
```

Are my indexes wrong!? Why does it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a CAST on the dateend field.  When you perform a function on a field it will not use the index for that field.  If possible I would recommend converting this field to a DATE data type.  And if the first field in an index is not used, the index will be ignored.

If the field is a DATETIME field, you do not use the CAST function.  Simply remove it and leave it as:

```
WHERE
    dateend >= CURDATE()
```

Any datetime value that is for today will match.  You do not need to remove the time.  For example.  2012-12-14 01:00:00 will be greater than or equal to 2012-12-14 (which the CURDATE function will return).

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately we need to keep the time in it; though I guess the other option is to create two fields, one as a `DATE` and the other as a `DATETIME`.

Comment: If the field is DATETIME, you do not have to change the data type.  I will edit my Answer.